# Return pointer or iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I'm rewriting a free function which takes a reference to a std::vector. Based on a given criteria, it then returns the index of the item in the vector or -1 if its not found. I would prefer if it returned a pointer to the item or a std::vector<>::iterator?

What should I consider when deciding what to return?

Comment: Are you aware of  [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) ?

Comment: Just to let you know: most std::vector<T>::iterator implementations is either lightweight wrapper to simple pointer or just pointer itself. However there are exceptions (`std::vector<bool>`) so use iterators.

Comment: @StackedCrooked Yes, I'm now going to look into using this function instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return an iterator, and `yourVector.end()` if the element is not found.

This is what the standard library uses.

Example:

```
auto my_function(std::vector<int>& v) -> decltype(v.begin())
{
    // Do the search
    ...
    else return v.end();
}
```

Better is if you can do

```
template <typename I>
I my_function(I begin, I end)
{
     // Do the search
     ...
     else return end;
}

template <typename C>
auto my_function(C&& c) -> decltype(std::begin(c))
{
    return my_function(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

because it will work for any container (including arrays):

```
double my_array[] = { 1, 2, 42, -7 };
auto p = my_function(my_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the idiomatic way of returning an interator and if the item wasn't found, return `.end()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely return an `std::vector<>::iterator`, and here is why:

When you treat a data structure, you should always give out the correct "accession objects". If you use an actual array (`int[]`), you can give out pointers. But for std::vector<>, the correct "accession objects" are iterators and you should never access elements in the vector by pointers.

You can return `your_vec.end()` to signal that the element was not found.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are inventing a new term here. Your "accession objects" are just iterators. Yes, for arrays you use pointers, but pointers to an array are a form of iterators too.

Comment: That's because I didn't want to confuse the person asking the question: he asked for a choice between "pointers" and "std::vector<>::iterator" and saying that they are both iterators anyway would have been confusing, so I went with inventing a new word.